# Uploading image from Android to GCS

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage, google-api-java-client

I am trying to upload an image from Android directly to Google cloud storage. But the API does not seem to work. They have some Java samples which are tied to the App engine. I don't see any sample which is proven to work on Android.

On Android, I tried using the json api to upload an image. I am able to upload an image object but it seems to be corrupt. Moreover generating the authentication token seems to be tricky too.

I am struck with this right now. Did anyone on this earth ever tried uploading an image/video from Android using Java client or Json API and succeeded? Can someone point me in the right direction please. It has been very disappointing experience with this Storage api from Google. Please share your experiences if someone did it.
Below is the code that I am trying from Android while trying to use the GCS's JSON API.

```
private static String uploadFile(RichMedia media) {
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapUtils.getBitmap(media.getLocalUrl());
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(GCS_ROOT + media.getLocalUrl() + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis());
    if(media.getType() == RichMedia.RichMediaType.PICTURE) {
        post.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
    } else {
        post.setHeader("Content-Type", "video/mp4");
    }
    post.setHeader("Authorization", "AIzaSyCzdmCMwiMzl6LD7R2obF0xSgnnx5rEfeI");
    //post.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(bitmap.getByteCount()));
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

    try {
        post.setEntity(new StringEntity(new Gson().toJson(byteArray).toString()));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String eachLine = null;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((eachLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(eachLine);
        }
        L.d("response = " + builder.toString());
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
        String name = object.getString("name");
        return  name;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        L.print(e);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        L.print(e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

I am running into two issues here.

1. The file which got uploaded to the server is corrupt. It is not the same image that I uploaded. It is currupt.
2. The authorization key expires very often. In my case, I am using the auth code generated by gsutil.

Comment: Yes, this should work. Could you please share your code and elaborate on what you mean by "corrupt"?

Comment: Added some code and the specific issues that I am running into.

Comment: Why aren't you using the [google-api-java-client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) ?

Comment: I did not find any sample piece of code which is using google api java client. I am not familiar with that piece. Can you help me point in the right direction?

Comment: The answer to that question can be found here:

[using-google-cloud-storage-json-api-in-android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21953744/using-google-cloud-storage-json-api-in-android/23594667#23594667

Comment: Can you shed some light on this please Gopinath? We are all stuck with this issue and the lack of documentation. Do you have the steps for uploading images/videos to Google Cloud Storage from Android?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since no one is answering this question, let me update the way I solved this problem. I ended up following this https://github.com/pliablematter/simple-cloud-storage project.

I could upload Pictures/Videos to GCS from my Android app.

Comment: Hey, i also want to do same functionality in android but the code you provided is java code.So can you give some guidelines for using it in android. And where i have to keep `cloudestorage.properties` and `private key` files?

Comment: I have made a base64 encoded string of the contents of the private key as a constant in my project. Then I am creating a file on the application private files by decoding this string. I am later pointing to this file for the authentication, which worked in my case. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Gopinath,I am also trying to upload image to google cloud storage from android client.Can you please share your code snippet of image uploading for android client?

Comment: @Gopinath ,I am getting following error , when I issue this command "mvn clean install" , Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project simple-cloud-storage: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: How to fix it?

Comment: @Gopinath,I solved above mentioned issue.But I run into new problem. when I issue mvn clean install , following error occures. java.io.FileNotFoundException: var/e9-privatekey (No such file or directory).Please give me any suggestion .

Comment: @BABUK please share sample source code  can't make it working mvn clean install i have a gradle based project

Comment: @Gopinath When you said you are creating a file by decoding the string, is it converted back to a .p12 file ? Would you be able to share the code snippet which shows the encoding part of .p12 file to a string and then converting back the string to a file again?

Comment: Is it safe to bundle the p12 file with the app. Could anybody else use the same file to extract data from your storage?

Answer (score 8):

Fixed for Android:

Android Studio config:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('google-play-services.jar')
    compile 'com.wu-man:android-oauth-client:0.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:v1-rev17-1.19.0'
    compile(group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client', version:'1.19.0'){
        exclude(group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5')
    }
}
```

AndroidManifiest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Main implementation:

```
    new AsyncTask(){

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
            try {

                CloudStorage.uploadFile("bucket-xxx", "photo.jpg");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                if(DEBUG)Log.d(TAG, "Exception: "+e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
```

CloudStorage Class:

```
import com.google.api.services.storage.Storage;
import com.google.api.services.storage.StorageScopes;
import com.google.api.services.storage.model.Bucket;
import com.google.api.services.storage.model.StorageObject;

public static void uploadFile(String bucketName, String filePath)throws Exception {

    Storage storage = getStorage();
    StorageObject object = new StorageObject();
    object.setBucket(bucketName);
    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = new File(sdcard,filePath);

    InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);

    try {
        String contentType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(stream);
        InputStreamContent content = new InputStreamContent(contentType,stream);

        Storage.Objects.Insert insert = storage.objects().insert(bucketName, null, content);
        insert.setName(file.getName());
        insert.execute();

    } finally {
        stream.close();
    }
}

private static Storage getStorage() throws Exception {

    if (storage == null) {
        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
        List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();
        scopes.add(StorageScopes.DEVSTORAGE_FULL_CONTROL);

        Credential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                .setServiceAccountId(ACCOUNT_ID_PROPERTY) //Email                           
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(getTempPkc12File())
                .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes).build();

        storage = new Storage.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory,
            credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME_PROPERTY)
            .build();
    }

    return storage;
}

private static File getTempPkc12File() throws IOException {
    // xxx.p12 export from google API console
    InputStream pkc12Stream = AppData.getInstance().getAssets().open("xxx.p12");
    File tempPkc12File = File.createTempFile("temp_pkc12_file", "p12");
    OutputStream tempFileStream = new FileOutputStream(tempPkc12File);

    int read = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    while ((read = pkc12Stream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        tempFileStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
    }
    return tempPkc12File;
}
```

Comment: can u plz tell ...what is storage?

Comment: Hey mate your code is incomplete, can you edit the code please? :)

Comment: ready, I added missing imports (not all, but the most important)

Comment: how can i check file is successfully uploaded to cloud? Is there another way apart from list the bucket files? How can i get response which is get from cloud?

Comment: Is it safe to bundle the p12 file with the app. Could anybody else use the same file to extract data from your storage?

Comment: am getting this error  " uploadFile Error code: null"  at insert.execute();

Comment: i am getting this error Getting error any one any idea  `com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
    {
      "error" : "invalid_grant",
      "error_description" : "Robot is missing a project number."
    } `

Answer (score 3):

This snippet of code works for me great for uploading files from Android directly to GCS.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), fileName);

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

        FileBody filebody = new FileBody(file,ContentType.create(mimeType), file.getName());

        MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();        
        multipartEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        multipartEntity.addPart("file", filebody);
        httppost.setEntity(multipartEntity.build());
        System.out.println( "executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine( ) );
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute( httppost );
            Log.i("response", response.getStatusLine().toString());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        httpclient.getConnectionManager( ).shutdown( );
```

MultipartEntityBuilder class is not included into android standard libraries so you need to download [httpclient](https://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi) and include into your project.

Comment: Which Url should I have to include in HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url); line of your code? . And did you upload image to google cloud storage?

Comment: @BABUK URL for uploading files could look like this `http://storage.googleapis.com/<your bucket name>/yourfilename.jpg`. Read [this](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference-uris) for the reference.

Comment: Hi, What about credentials? Where do you authenticate? I receive 403 forbidden with your code... thx!

Answer (score 2):

Hpsaturn's answer worked for me. He missed to answer a few points. How to get service account id and p12 file. For getting these 2, open console.developers.google.com and choose your project. Enable Cloud Storage API. You see a message to create credentials. Go to credentials in API manager and create credential by selecting Service account key and follow the details in image. You will get the service account id and p12 file from this screen.

[image]

Hpsaturn also missed to mention AppData, which is your custom Application class defined in manifest. For everyone's convenience, I am attaching the complete CloudStorage class here.

```
package com.abc.xyz.utils;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

import com.abc.xyz.app.AppController;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.InputStreamContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.storage.Storage;
import com.google.api.services.storage.StorageScopes;
import com.google.api.services.storage.model.StorageObject;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by wjose on 8/20/2016.
 */
public class CloudStorage {

    private static final String TAG = "CloudStorage";

    public static void uploadFile(String bucketName, String name, Uri uri)throws Exception {

        Storage storage = getStorage();
        StorageObject object = new StorageObject();
        object.setBucket(bucketName);
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        //File file = new File(sdcard,filePath);
        File file = new File(uri.getPath());

        InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);

        try {
            String contentType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(stream);
            InputStreamContent content = new InputStreamContent(contentType,stream);

            Storage.Objects.Insert insert = storage.objects().insert(bucketName, null, content);
            insert.setName(name);
            StorageObject obj = insert.execute();
            Log.d(TAG, obj.getSelfLink());
        } finally {
            stream.close();
        }
    }

    static Storage storage = null;
    private static Storage getStorage() throws Exception {

        if (storage == null) {
            HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
            JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
            List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();
            scopes.add(StorageScopes.DEVSTORAGE_FULL_CONTROL);

            Credential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setTransport(httpTransport)
                    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                    .setServiceAccountId("myuser-801@xxxyyyzzz.iam.gserviceaccount.com") //Email
                    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(getTempPkc12File())
                    .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes).build();

            storage = new Storage.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory,
                    credential).setApplicationName("MyApp")
                    .build();
        }

        return storage;
    }

    private static File getTempPkc12File() throws IOException {
        // xxx.p12 export from google API console
        InputStream pkc12Stream = MyApplication.getInstance().getAssets().open("xxxyyyzzz-0c80eed2e8aa.p12");
        File tempPkc12File = File.createTempFile("temp_pkc12_file", "p12");
        OutputStream tempFileStream = new FileOutputStream(tempPkc12File);
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        while ((read = pkc12Stream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            tempFileStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        return tempPkc12File;
    }
}
```

btb, I used only following dependency in the gradle.

> compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:+'

Comment: Application class

Comment: @Winster where should i add the downloaded .P12 file in my android project?

Comment: am getting this error any one any idea 
  `com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
    {
      "error" : "invalid_grant",
      "error_description" : "Robot is missing a project number."
    }`

Answer (score 2):

I have tried all the above answers and none of them worked for me straight out of the box. 
Here is what i have done to make it working(only by editing from the above comments):

```
package  Your page name;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.InputStreamContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.storage.Storage;
import com.google.api.services.storage.StorageScopes;
import com.google.api.services.storage.model.Bucket;
import com.google.api.services.storage.model.StorageObject;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

 public class CloudStorage {

static Activity activity=null;
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002293/uploading-image-from-android-to-gcs

static Storage storage=null;
public static void uploadFile(Activity activity2,String bucketName, String filePath)
{
    activity=activity2;
    try {
        Storage storage = getStorage();
        StorageObject object = new StorageObject();
        object.setBucket(bucketName);
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(filePath);

        InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);

        try {
            Log.d("Alkamli","Test");
            String contentType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(stream);
            InputStreamContent content = new InputStreamContent(contentType, stream);

            Storage.Objects.Insert insert = storage.objects().insert(bucketName, null, content);
            insert.setName(file.getName());
            insert.execute();

        } finally {
            stream.close();
        }
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        class Local {}; Log.d("Alkamli","Sub: "+Local.class.getEnclosingMethod().getName()+" Error code: "+e.getMessage());

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static Storage getStorage() {

    try {

        if (storage == null)
        {
            HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
            JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
            List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();
            scopes.add(StorageScopes.DEVSTORAGE_FULL_CONTROL);

            Credential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setTransport(httpTransport)
                    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                    .setServiceAccountId("Service-Email-Address") //Email
                    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(getTempPkc12File())
                    .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes).build();

            storage = new Storage.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory,
                    credential)
                    .build();
        }

        return storage;
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        class Local {}; Log.d("Alkamli","Sub: "+Local.class.getEnclosingMethod().getName()+" Error code: "+e.getMessage());

    }
    Log.d("Alkamli","Storage object is null ");
    return null;
}

private static File getTempPkc12File() {
    try {
        // xxx.p12 export from google API console
        InputStream pkc12Stream = activity.getResources().getAssets().open("Service-key.p12");
        File tempPkc12File = File.createTempFile("temp_pkc12_file", "p12");
        OutputStream tempFileStream = new FileOutputStream(tempPkc12File);
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        while ((read = pkc12Stream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            tempFileStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        return tempPkc12File;
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        class Local {}; Log.d("Alkamli","Sub: "+Local.class.getEnclosingMethod().getName()+" Error code: "+e.getMessage());

    }
    Log.d("Alkamli"," getTempPkc12File is null");
    return null;
}
}
```

I only edited few lines to make it work for me and for the dependencies in gradle You will need only these three. (Keep in mind that if you use all google depenacnes that may damage your whole project. in my case some of android's functions wouldn't work anymore )

```
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:v1-rev17-1.19.0'
```

The full project for people  needing it :
https://github.com/Fahad-alkamli/Chat-app

Comment: @goto dude i am not asking a question ? only giving an updated solution. You should read first before writing comments and giving negative feedback.

Comment: @FahadAlkamli I am getting  com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found.{
      "code" : 404,
      "errors" : [ {
        "domain" : "global",
        "message" : "Not Found",
        "reason" : "notFound"
      } ],
      "message" : "Not Found"
    }
Any Idea?

Comment: What does bucket name represent?

Comment: @Taslim I believe it to be the bucket name you have created using google console. , for example you would create image bucket to store images etc..

Comment: @FahadAlkamli where should i  put  my .P12 file in android project ?

Comment: @syed irfan  I really don't remember but this is the full project on github for your needs:https://github.com/Fahad-alkamli/Chat-app

Comment: @FahadAlkamli thanks Fahad i got it you have put it in your asset folder

Answer (score 2):

Not so Surprisingly, none of the solutions above worked for me. The REASON, well in all the above answers they're using the .P12 file, while I got a JSON file as an api key. There are these two different keys which I didn't know at first and I thought I was doing wrong and after one intense day of going through google docs, stackoverflow I was finally able to upload to the storage. None of the above answers show on how to do it for a JSON file and the code is tad bit simple so I'm posting this answers, hope this helps someone:

UploadFile.java

```
public class UploadFile {

    public static Storage setCredentials(InputStream credentialFile) {
        InputStream credentialsStream = null;;
        Credentials credentials = null;
        try {
            credentialsStream = credentialFile;
            credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(credentialsStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return StorageOptions.newBuilder()
                .setProjectId("YOUR_PROJECT_ID").setCredentials(credentials)
                .build().getService();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public static String transmitImageFile(Storage storage, String srcFileName, String newName) {
        File file = new File(srcFileName);
        byte[] fileContent = null;
        try {
            fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        if (fileContent == null)
            return null;
        if (fileContent.length == 0)
            return null;
        BlobInfo.Builder newBuilder = Blob.newBuilder(BucketInfo.of("YOUR_BUCKET_NAME"), newName);
        BlobInfo blobInfo = newBuilder.setContentType("image/png").build();
        Blob blob = storage.create(blobInfo, fileContent);
        String bucket = blob.getBucket();
        String contentType = blob.getContentType();
        Log.e("TAG", "transmitImageFile: "+contentType);
        System.out.println("File " + srcFileName + " uploaded to bucket " + bucket + " as " + newName);
        return newName;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String currentPhotoPath;
    private String imageName;
    public static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    private File photoFile = null;
    private String[] permissions;
    public static final int PERMISSION_REQ_CODE = 200;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView textView= findViewById(R.id.textView);
        permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};
        PermissionsRequest();
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
                ReadFromAsset();
            }
        });
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getPackageName(), photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        String fileName = "temp";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg");

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        imageName = image.getName();

        return image;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Storage storage = UploadFile.setCredentials(getAssets().open("GoogleMapDemo.json"));
                        UploadFile.transmitImageFile(storage, currentPhotoPath, "sampleImage.jpg");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            thread.start();
            Log.e("TAG", "ImagePath: " + currentPhotoPath);
            Log.e("TAG", "ImageName: " + imageName);
        }
    }

    private void PermissionsRequest() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), permissions[0]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), permissions[4]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder1.setTitle("AAtten");
            builder1.setMessage("Permissions");
            builder1.setCancelable(false);
            builder1.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    acceptPermissions();
                }
            });
            builder1.setNegativeButton("SAIR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
            //Creating dialog box
            AlertDialog alert1 = builder1.create();
            alert1.show();
        }
    }

    private void acceptPermissions() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), permissions[0]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), permissions[1]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), permissions[2]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), permissions[3]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), permissions[4]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), permissions[5]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSION_REQ_CODE);
            else {
                if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), permissions[0]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), permissions[1]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), permissions[2]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), permissions[3]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), permissions[4]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), permissions[5]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSION_REQ_CODE);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ReadFromAsset(){
        String string = "";
        try {
            //InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(String.valueOf(getAssets().open("key.p12")));
            InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("GoogleMapDemo.json");
            int size = inputStream.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            inputStream.read(buffer);
            string = new String(buffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e("TAG", "ReadFromAsset: "+string );
    }
}
```

Now google on how to create a asset folder in the app and add the json key file in that folder. In onActivityResult class you'll pass the name of the json file.

And in UploadImage class give your projectID and bucketName in respective feilds. You can find the projectID in that json.file

Dependencies

```
android{
 packagingOptions{
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
}

    implementation platform('com.google.cloud:libraries-bom:16.2.1')
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage'
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-core:1.94.0'
```

Maifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">

<application
  <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.personalgooglestoragecheck"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
</application
```

file-path.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path
        name="my_images"
        path="/" />
    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="." />

    <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="." />
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Hope this helps someone. Any questions feel free to ask.

EDIT 1:

Apparently Files.readAllBytes() is introduced in Java 7 and only works on Android api 26 or above. If you want to target lower versions use fileinputstream and remove all the @requireannotation tags.