# Android example for google cloud storage

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I want to upload and download images and media files from my android application to google cloud store.

When I try a java sample on https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-java-samples

it shows me below errors,
Can anyone advice me here, or can anyone show me the links form where do I get help for integrating this to android applications,

```
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.1:java (default-cli) @ storage-cmd-line-sample ---
Jan 22, 2015 10:08:34 AM com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
WARNING: unable to change permissions for everybody: C:\Users\USER\.store\storage_sample
Jan 22, 2015 10:08:34 AM com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
WARNING: unable to change permissions for owner: C:\Users\USER\.store\storage_sample
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:191)
        at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:127)
        at com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory.createJsonParser(JacksonFactory.java:92)
        at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:85)
        at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:81)
        at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:88)
        at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
        at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
        at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.executeRefreshToken(Credential.java:570)
        at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
        at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:859)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
        at StorageSample.main(StorageSample.java:125)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:290)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Regards

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002293/uploading-image-from-android-to-gcs help?

Comment: Yes, I checked this link and it seems that a project on this link is working.
https://github.com/pliablematter/simple-cloud-storage

But can I access my images through URLs? for example this project has a method   CloudStorage.downloadFile which downloads it to local folder. But I want to access images using URLs, is it possible?

Comment: Yup. http://storage.googleapis.com/<<BUCKET NAME>>/<<FILE NAME>>

Comment: @BhavinMistry it seems like you have resolved your issue, can you post your solution as an answer so that other users with the similar issue can benefit from it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As this question still gets many views I will post the user's solution from the comments.

The issue was resolved by following the tutorial at https://github.com/pliablematter/simple-cloud-storage. At the time of this post, that link is 4 years out of date, so a better solution at this time would be to use the **updated official sample** at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/storage/json-api.

Cloud storage objects can be accessed via URL in the form `https://storage.cloud.google.com/<bucket>/<object>`, which is mentioned at various times throughout the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/collaboration).