# Uploading Video file from an Android Client to a Google Bucket?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, file-upload, google-cloud-storage

Utterly surprised there isn't a proper documentation for setting up this. I need to allow the facility to upload a video file or an image file to a Google Bucket from an Android Application. What is the procedure for this?

- Do I upload the file to the Backend and the backend uploads it to the Bucket
- Do I upload the file directly to the bucket

I managed to set up a Google Bucket on my cloud and according to their [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload), I'm supposed to send the file as a POST request?

What their documentation shows:

```
POST /upload/storage/v1/b/myBucket/o?uploadType=media&name=myObject HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: number_of_bytes_in_file
Authorization: Bearer your_auth_token

JPEG data
```

Can someone kindly direct me to a Java implementation of posting a video file to my Bucket storage?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002293/uploading-image-from-android-to-gcs

Comment: Did you find a solution? It would be really helpful if you could provide the solution you came up with.