# Google Cloud StorageException: Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.create access to the Google Cloud Storage object

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to upload images to the Google Cloud Storage Client and I get this exception, I've tried searching regarding this but there are no question regarding this issue in android and unable to go forward, here is my code:

MainActivity.Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String currentPhotoPath;
    private String imageName;
    public static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    private File photoFile = null;
    private String[] permissions;
    public static final int PERMISSION_REQ_CODE = 200;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView textView= findViewById(R.id.textView);
        permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};
        acceptPermissions();

        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            }
        });
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getPackageName(), photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        String fileName = "temp";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(fileName, ".jpg");
        currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        imageName = image.getName();
        return image;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try  {
                        UploadObject.uploadObject("project_id", "bucktedname", imageName, currentPhotoPath);                       
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            thread.start();          
        }
    }

    private void acceptPermissions() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), permissions[0]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), permissions[1]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), permissions[2]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), permissions[3]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), permissions[4]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), permissions[5]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSION_REQ_CODE);
            else {
                if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), permissions[0]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), permissions[1]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), permissions[2]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), permissions[3]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), permissions[4]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), permissions[5]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSION_REQ_CODE);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

UploadObject.Java

```
public class UploadObject {
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public static void uploadObject(
            String projectId, String bucketName, String objectName, String filePath) throws IOException {

        Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(projectId).build().getService();
        BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucketName, objectName);
        BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).build();
        storage.create(blobInfo, Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)));
        System.out.println(
                "File " + filePath + " uploaded to bucket " + bucketName + " as " + objectName);
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
W/System.err: com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.create access to the Google Cloud Storage object.
        at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.translate(HttpStorageRpc.java:232)
        at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.create(HttpStorageRpc.java:313)
        at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl$3.call(StorageImpl.java:221)
W/System.err:     at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl$3.call(StorageImpl.java:218)
        at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:105)
        at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:76)
        at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50)
        at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.internalCreate(StorageImpl.java:217)
        at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.create(StorageImpl.java:171)
W/System.err:     at com.example.googlecloudstorgae.UploadObject.uploadObject(UploadObject.java:35)
        at com.example.googlecloudstorgae.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:111)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
W/System.err: Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
    POST https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/"bucket-Name"/o?projection=full&uploadType=multipart
W/System.err: {
      "code" : 401,
      "errors" : [ {
        "domain" : "global",
        "location" : "Authorization",
        "locationType" : "header",
        "message" : "Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.create access to the Google Cloud Storage object.",
        "reason" : "required"
      } ],
W/System.err:   "message" : "Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.create access to the Google Cloud Storage object."
    }
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:118)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:37)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:532)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:455)
W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:565)
        at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.create(HttpStorageRpc.java:310)
        ... 10 more
```

I've followed the documentation from the official google documentation, [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-code-sample). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Either your current account haven't the permission, or the bucket name is wrong (and you try to write in another bucket, and yes you haven't the permission)

Comment: Issues resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65664811/14401306) is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an authorization issue.

```
"code" : 401,
"message" : "Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.create access to the Google Cloud Storage object.
```

You might have to check the access for the user with which you are trying to access the bucket.
Either you can **check the privileges** if you have the dashboard access. OR try **performing the same operation using the same json certificate with gsutil**.